# Looking for free react native ide for windows

Tags: react-native, window

i am looking for a free react native IDE for windows.
Webstorm is not free, and Deco is for mac.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [vs-code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by microsoft or [Atom](https://atom.io/) by github.
They both have react-native plugins you can try.
[react-native plugin for vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native)
[react-native-autocomplete plugin for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-autocomplete).

These are just two plugins from a quick search on the web. I'm sure there are more.
I'm using vscode with its react-native plugin and i don't need more than that.

Comment: I tried Atom and installed the Nuclide plugin, but it's just coloring the code, nothing more. I am looking for an IDE where you can actually run and debug the code.

Comment: Then you really need to try Visual studio code. You can add breakpoints to your react native code even :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) - open source, Atom based IDE for React Native developed by Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recomend you [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). You will find a lot of plugins very kind and helpful